# Loading JSON contents using django framework

Tags: python, json, django, djongo

How can I load all the contents of a JSON file into my project?? I am using Python-Django as my backend and MongoDB as my database. I am trying to store the contents of JSON file onto MongoDB (Djongo)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import os
import json
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage

path = 'path/to/file.json'
default_storage.open(path).read()

# You may have to decode from Bytes to utf-8
# If you need to parse it to an array:
json = json.loads(data)
```